# Aar module in an Android Multimodular project

Tags: android, aar, multi-module

**Background**

Hi, currently I have an Android multimodular project & it looks like this.

- App
- Common
- Mod1
- Mod2
- Mod3

1. App will depend on Common, Mod1, Mod2 & Mod3.
2. Mod1, Mod2 & Mod3 will depend on Common.
3. Common, Mod1, Mod2, Mod3 are all individual Android library.

**Objective**

To aar selected modules to prevent altering of codes.

**Questions**

1. Case 1: if I need to aar Common only within this project, while the rest of the modules including App remain in original code form, what should be the recommended way to do it, so that the app will still run properly?
2. Case 2: Similarly, if I need to aar Mod1 and Common only within the project, what is the recommended approach?

Thanks a lot.
Rk